# Unpermitted parameter: user_id error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

am using devise for authentication in a rails app everything is working fine, but i have a post model and after signing up when i try to create a new post it shows up an error:

```
1 error prohibited this post from being saved:
User must exist
```

I looked into the terminal and got this:

```
Unpermitted parameter: user_id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

i tried adding a user controller
**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :check_ownership, only: [:edit, :update]
  respond_to :html, :js

# GET /users
      # GET /users.json
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      # GET /users/1
      # GET /users/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /users/new
      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      # GET /users/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /users
      # POST /users.json
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /users/1
      # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /users/1
      # DELETE /users/1.json
      def destroy
        @user.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to users_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
        end
    end
```

**my posts_controler.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:tittle, :body)
    end
end
```

**My user model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

         has_many :posts
end
```

**My post model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

i have also added user_id to user through this migration:

```
class AddUseridToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to permit :user_id as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the error says, permit the `user_id` as follows

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:tittle, :body, :user_id)
end
```

Or, better approach is you generate a new post for the logged_in user as in post create:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  # ...other logic
end
```

This way, you don't need to allow `user_id` also, it will ensure that the params are not tampered with..

Answer (score 1):

If you add column in your model, you should add it to your permitted params. So add `:user_id` in your permitted params in `posts_controller`:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:tittle, :body, :user_id)
end
```